# How to run a powershell script remotely on a USER account that has no password?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have to remove Skype from a number of computers on a network, I have created a powershell script with some information from online which does this if I run it locally on a user account which has no password.

I decided to save the PS1 file and a shared transfer folder however, when I try to trigger that file on all the computers it runs using the system account I believe on the computer and not the current user that I'm logged on to.

I also have I loop that I can include a script that will run on every machine by invoke-command but when I put the command to remove Skype within that powershell script and deploy on all servers it runs you again as SYSTEM which results on the script completing successfully, just not targeting the correct account on each machine (which I believe is the reason it's not removing Skype)

Get-AppxPackage *Microsoft. SkypeApp* | Remove-AppxPackage

Comment: Did you try the `-User` parameter of `Remove-AppXPackage` ? see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/remove-appxpackage?view=win10-ps

Comment: "when I try to trigger that file on all the computers" - how and from where are you doing this? Windows prohibits _network logons_* for accounts with blank passwords by default. (*) including PowerShell remoting sessions and WMI/RPC calls

Comment: Not to mention double hop if you’re invoking from A to B and trying to pull script from C

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `-AllUsers` parameter for the `Remove-AppxPackage` cmdlet. You can use this as a user with a password, in order to remotely work on the behalf of a user without a password. The below code removes the app for **all users** on the system that have logged on and have the app installed. Be careful, if you want the Skype app to be available for some users after this, this is not the solution for you. Here is my suggested code:

```
Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.SkypeApp -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
```

This method requires running PowerShell as an Administrator, because you will be trying to list other users' packages and remove them without their permission.

I recommend using the `-AllUsers` parameter for `Get-AppxPackage` as well, because it only changes the output slightly (in a way that does not require any changes to your code) and because it will find a `Microsoft.SkypeApp` package even if the current user (you) doesn't have it installed (as long as *someone* has it installed on the system of course).

If the AppxPackage *can* be removed, the above method will remove it. There are cases where Microsoft has decided you need an app and may not, under any circumstances (besides some interesting hacking that may result in unintended consequences) remove it. In that case, you will get an error that basically tells you the app is part of the OS and cannot be removed. From there, good luck. I have given up fighting Microsoft on allowing the Microsoft.XboxGameCallableUI package to exist for every Windows user in my org. They win, if they want to. At least I can remove Candy Crush.

Comment: Thanks @dustyvargas So I put the code example you kindly gave me within a PS1 file, I then placed it within the folder, ran this bach to trigger it did run with error 0 but when I checked on each computer the app was still there aghh....

Excuse my formatting im  new here

`@echo on
psexec \\COMPUTER001 powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Transfer\PowerShell Scripts\removeskype.ps1"
psexec \\COMPUTER002 powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Transfer\PowerShell Scripts\removeskype.ps1"`

Comment: I haven't used `psexec` for this purpose so I can't comment on that. What I have used is PSRemoting, and I was able to remove an app for two users with my posted code by using the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet remotely. Have you considered using PSRemoting?

Comment: PSRemoting is fairly simple to configure. With that enabled, you can run this to accomplish your goal: `Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'target.company.com' -ScriptBlock {Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.SkypeApp -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers}` -- the only file you might need is a CSV with all the hostnames of your win 10 workstations. That way you can easily store the names in an array with `Import-Csv` and use `foreach` to run that command against all your computers in one go.

Comment: it seemed to run through the loop, I checked one of the computers however and skype is still there agh...

I used

`ForEach ($s in 1.114) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName ('COMPUTER{0:d3}' -f $s) -ScriptBlock {
        Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.SkypeApp
    }
}`

Comment: start more simple. start with just one computer, and run this command: `Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'computer01' -ScriptBlock {Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.SkypeApp -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers}`

Comment: if that works, you can begin learning how to use `foreach` and work your way up to removing the package from all your computers. I don't know what you're doing with `($s in 1.114)` but I think it would be easier to put your computer names in a CSV and use `Import-Csv`, so you can do this: `foreach ($computer in $computers) {Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {Remove-AppxPackage .....}}`

Comment: [COMPUTER001] Connecting to remote server COMPUTER001 failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. If the authentication scheme is different from Kerberos ...ETC ETC

Comment: I don't know man, you're gonna have to troubleshoot WinRM on your own. See the following link. It has an example `psexec` command to enable powershell remoting, which seems like something you're familiar with. https://4sysops.com/wiki/enable-powershell-remoting/

Comment: Fantastic cheers, is there a command I can run that tells me if WinRM is enabled on the machines? that I can run in my loop?